# Data loading in grid only after clicking on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, grid

I have a strange behavior in my angular website grid.

Whenever my page load, data will show as blank. But if i click and leave focus in any of the text boxes in the page, data will be loaded in the grid.

Load event is already called in onInit, and never called again when i leave focus of text box.

What is the possible reason for this?

Comment: Maybe you're triggering the (change) event by setting and losing focus and there is some onChange logic?

Comment: <table-dataheader [result]= value (changed)="rowsOnPage=$event"></table-dataheader>

Comment: <input class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Filter From/To Date to download PDF"
                                [style.width]="'350px'"
                                [(ngModel)]="dateTime1" name="date2"
                                [selectMode]="'range'"
                                [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtRange1" [owlDateTime]="dtRange1" (ngModelChange)="dateRangeFrom(dtRange1)">
                         <owl-date-time #dtRange1></owl-date-time>

                            </div>

Comment: only two textboxes and change event shown above

Comment: It was also with me too so i solve my issue lkie 
add button in html and set display hide
<button id='button' style='display:none;'>click<button>
and use bellow code in your function after response back
document.getElementById('button').click()

Comment: u mean i need to place a add button and make it hide? can you show some code

Comment: i have edit my comment check it

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3"><button style='display:none;'>click</button> 
    
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keyup)="searchFilter()">
                            </div>

Comment: i did like above , but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found

changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

In my code, i removed it and worked, thanks